# defining the CHAR pointer with variable size

Tags: c, pointers

How can I define a char pointer with the correct with or variable width?

My scenario is below..

```
void processRa(int _raCount, char *raFile)
{
    char *command; // How to correctly define this variable ?
    sprintf(command, "somecomm -r %s -N%d-%d ", raFile, (_raCount - 1), (_raCount - 1));
    system(command);
}
```

in the scenario, I am defining a char pointer `command`. The size of the `command` depends on the function passed variable `raFile` and the following line's command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char*` in C come without associated storage. This is different from languages like fortran where the character type stands for a string of fixed size. You either have to define a character *array* using something like `char command[size+1]`, or you use `malloc()` to do the allocation (don't forget to call `free()` when you are done with the string).

The tricky part is to correctly compute the required length. However, in the POSIX-2008 standard, there is already a function called `asprintf()`, that does precisely what you need: It combines the function of `sprintf()` with the allocation of enough memory using `malloc()` (again, don't forget to call `free()` when you are done with the string). Usage is as follows:

```
void processRa(int _raCount, char *raFile) {
    char *command; // How to correctly define this variable ?
    asprintf(&command, "somecomm -r %s -N%d-%d ", raFile, (_raCount - 1), (_raCount - 1));
    system(command);
    free(command);
}
```

Comment: I choosed this answer. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate it dynamically:

```
char *command = malloc(strlen(raFile) + N));
```

Where N is maximum possible length of the rest of the target string (includes null-terminator, static text and two dynamic integers in your case).

Comment: is it wrong if i do 
`char command[sizeof(raFile) + N]` ? what is the different between your reply and this? please explain.

Comment: you just _can't_ do that, array size must be a constant expression in C.

Comment: And that's why we use dynamic memory allocation when the size of memory is calculated in runtime.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Sorry to contradict, but in C, you *can* do `char command[sizeof(raFile) + N]`. It's just C++ that does not allow variable length arrays. Its one of the really nasty differences between the languages.

Comment: @cmaster you surely mean C99 or later, right? I always considered C99 a different language than C90, not sure why. Maybe because many commercial IT companies still use C90...

Comment: @AlexShesterov Yes, I was referring to the more up to date standards. C90 is already 24 years old, that's from the stone age... And the C99 and C11 standards added some really useful things that I would not want to code without.

Answer (score 1):

```
int raFileLen = strlen( raFileLen ) ;
int extraInfo = strlen( "somecomm -r -N" ) + (sizeof(int)*2) + raFileLen + 10 ; 
// 10 bytes:: just to be safe

char* command = malloc( extraInfo ) ;
if( command == NULL ) return -1 ;

// Codes .... Codes

free( command ) ;
```

Comment: ok I got why you are adding extra 10 bytes. and why you use this part `(sizeof(int)*2)` ?

Comment: You can say, it is also a "just-to-be-safe" methodology. Giving "sizeof(char)*2" would be enough though.

Answer (score 1):

```
somecomm = 8
-r = 2
%s = strlen(raFile)
-N = 2
%d = max 10 digits = 10 * 2  = 20
spaces = 4 (the trailing space also included)
-----------------------------------
total = 37 (one for '\0') + strlen(raFile);
-----------------------------------
```

I would say `malloc(37 + strlen(raFile));` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you i believe:

```
command = malloc(strlen(raFile)+someBytes);
```

Of course i assume that `raFile` is null terminated.

Comment: Since the OP is writing the whole of raFile + a lot of extras, this will cause a seg fault.

Comment: @Lundin Yes sure. I got that issue.